# css3 keyframes animation not working

Tags: html, css

Have researched this a fair bit but can't seem to find asolution.
I have created a site but wanted to add a pure CSS slider/slideshow and am just experimenting with some examples in a book I have. However, no animation occurs, tested without the -webkit prefixes in IE and the animation failed there too. Here is the code;

html

```
<div class="container">
  <section class="runner">

  </section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   .container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1100px
}

 .runner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(img/teams2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s    
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
    20% {background: url(img/teams2.jpg);}
    20%, 45% {background: url (img/logo.png);}
    50%, 70% {background: url (img/header.png);}
    75%, 95% {background: url (img/get_involved.png)}
}
```

Comment: really? the example I have listed above is actually an exact copy of the example in my book. How would you suggest doing it? Thanks

Comment: You have forget an ; after -webkit-perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an little error in you background definitions:

```
background: url (img/header.png);
```

should be

```
background: url(img/header.png);
```

Note an insidious space between `url` and `(`.

#### Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c6t6S/